# Ubuntu 18.04 bond with netplan duplicate MAC address after cloning

Tags: server, 18.04, netplan, clonezilla, network-bonding

I have a situation in which I have many identical servers to setup Ubuntu 18.04 on. I set one server up, took an image with Clonezilla and then restored on all others.

Normally, I go to each of these servers, then I apply the necessary changes to /etc/hostname, /etc/hosts and the netplan YAML file to reflect the correct settings.

The problem is that the bond I have configured in the netplan file always comes up with an identical MAC address to the server I took an image from, so the network fails completely.

Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by deleting the /etc/machine-id file and rebooting or just using the systemd-machine-id-setup utility.